# How to get the count of each value from different fields using Django Queries?

Tags: django, optimization

I have a Django model with many fields. Let's say the model is like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    foo_value = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True)
    # ... and many many other fields
```

Now I need to run a query to get me all the data from all fields. This would be `Foo.objects.all()`, right?

Now I need for each name (which means I will group by name) to do some things. First, the problem is if I want to group by name I would do this: `Foo.objects.values('name')`, right? But this gets me the '***name***' field value only for all records. I need all the other fields but grouped by ***name***.

The second more important thing is, I need to get the count of each distinct value in the '***type***' field as well as the sum of the '***foo_value***' field associated with each '***type***'. I need all this to be one record per '***name***' in the returned result. The issue is, if I tried this: `Foo.objects.values('name').annotate(c=Count('type'), s=Sum('foo_value'))`, it will get me a record for each ('***name***', '***type***') pair.
What I need is that if I have data like this:

> name    type    foo_value
>     x        t1        5.5
>     x        t1        10.0
>     x        t2        20.0
>     y        t2        15.23
>     y        t1        17.0

I need the result to be:

> name    type_t1_count    type_t1_sum    type_t2_count    type_t2_sum
>   x                2                15.5                                1                20.0
>   y                1                17.0                                1                15.23

How to achieve something like this?

Comment: _I need all the other fields but grouped by name._ - you can't get other fields because.. for example you have several models with the same name but other fields are different. Which model of several do you want to get? Seems like that you need `order_by`, not grouping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since django 1.8 has [conditional-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)
and you can try, and you shoul use `order_by` to exclude default group by read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField, FloatField

qs = Foo.objects.values('name'
                   ).annotate(type_t1_count=Count(
                        Case(
                           When(type='t1', then=1),
                           output_field=IntegerField()
                        )
                        )
                    ).annotate(type_t1_sum=Sum(
                        Case(
                           When(type='t1', then='foo_value'),
                           default=0.0,
                           output_field=FloatField()
                        )
                        )
                    ).annotate(type_t2_count=Count(
                        Case(
                           When(type='t2', then=1),
                           output_field=IntegerField()
                        )
                        )
                    ).annotate(type_t2_sum=Sum(
                        Case(
                           When(type='t2', then='foo_value'),
                           default=0.0,
                           output_field=FloatField()
                        )
                        )
                    ).order_by('name')
```

the result is:

```
[
    {'type_t1_sum': 15.5, 'type_t1_count': 2,
     'type_t2_count': 1, 'type_t2_sum': 20.0,
     'name': 'x'},
    {'type_t1_sum': 17.0, 'type_t1_count': 1,
    'type_t2_count': 1, 'type_t2_sum': 15.23,
    'name': 'y'}
]
```

Comment: thank you so much. This totally worked. I have one more thing if you can help me with. For one of the fields in my model, I need to calculate the mode value (The most common value). But it works like this:

Comment: It is a `DateTimeField` in the model. So I used to get the query and then get the day value using `q['event_time'].day` and then calculate the quarter of month using the `bisect` package. I then add all quarters for all records of the same user to a list and then get the mode of that list using the `numpy` stats package. 

So here is the code: 
`quarts = range(1, 31, 7);`  
`quarter = bisect(quarts, q['event_time'].day);`  
`month_quarts.append(quarter if quarter <= 4 else 4);`  
and then later I get the mode using `qm = mode(month_quarts);`

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the `When .. then` expression?

Comment: glad to help you, for your second question, i'm not sure that i understood you well, i recommend create a new question with description your business logic, after it your solution with examples of data, and more than only one(me) will read it and may be find good solution for you

Comment: will do that. Thanks