# Django query: how to apply the mode calculation in the query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985195/how-to-get-the-count-of-each-value-from-different-fields-using-django-queries) I was asking about how to do a complex query in Django. Here is my example model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    foo_value = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True)
    time_event = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    # ... and many many other fields
```

Now in my previous question @BearBrown [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986026/3573182) me with using the `When .. then` expression to control my query.

Now I need something more. I need to calculate the mode (most repeated value) of the quarter of the month in the `time_event` field. Manually, I do it like this:
- I manually iterate over all records for the same user.
- Get the day using `q['event_time'].day`
- Define quarters using `quarts = range(1, 31, 7)`
- Then, append the calculated quarters to a list `month_quarts.append(quarter if quarter <= 4 else 4)`
- Then get the mode value for this specific user `qm = mode(month_quarts)`

Is there a way to automate this mode calculation function in the When .. then expression instead of manually iterating through all records for every user and calculating it?